# Execute python code over SSH

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, paramiko

I need to write a python script which connects to the host over SSH and then somehow connects to a service sitting on `localhost` and performs a little interactive session.

What first came to mind is to use `Paramiko` to do a local port forwarding and then use Pythons's `sockets` library to communicate with the service.
But working with `Paramiko` was quite a challenge and I haven't figured out how to fix some issues.

So I switched to `pxssh` and used just simple scenario:

```
conn.sendline('telnet {} {}'.format('localhost', port)
conn.expect('PASSWORD:')
conn.sendline(password)
...
```

But that telnet thing really bothers me.
And I think it's possible to establish SSH connection in such a manner that from Python's code prospective I just do `data = open('somefile').read()` which actually opens a `somefile` on a remote host and all traffic is being encrypted because of SSH.

Comment: Can you detail your issues with Paramiko? Doing the `open` like you want doesn't seem trivial.

Comment: Well I took the `forward.py` example. And I wasn't sure how to detach the process which forwards the connection so I could continue with `socket` and so on .

Comment: Instead of creating a tunnel, why not execute a script instead? See [this](http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2012/10/11/using-paramiko-to-send-ssh-commands/) for example.

Comment: @vikramls how does the script appears on a server? What you suggest is to use exec_command and instead of using telnet - use python script. Both these methods I am not really satisfied with because I want to have more "control" over what is happening and do everything within one script.